# gradlew assembleRelease it gives the following error in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I want to make apk file of my application code, but whenever I am running **gradlew assembleRelease** it gives the following error, I just want to create the build with anything, as I have to deliver my project on Monday. Any help will be appreciated

```
 C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal\android>gradlew assembleRelease
    :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, undefined, config]' command.
    :ReactNative:Running '[node, undefined, config]' command failed.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script 'C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 170

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating script.
    > internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584    throw err;    ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal\android\undefined'    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 2s

    C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal\android>
```

Comment: check this [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27374)

Comment: Sorry m not able to understand, can you please explain in Answer?

Answer (score -2):

**Follow This Step:**

1) C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal> react-native run-android

2) C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal> cd android

3) C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\managementportal\android> ./gradlew assembleRelease

**All Process is done after getting release app**

Project folder > android > app > build > outputs > apk > release